# Nginx is taking the whole domain and not the subdomain

Tags: nginx

I've installed `Nginx` on a fresh EC2 instance (Amazon Linux 2) with a basic config file:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    root /var/www/html;

    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name atlasalgorithms.kadiemqazzaz.com;

    location / {
           try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
}
```

Now `Nginx` is serving both `http://atlasalgorithms.kadiemqazzaz.com` and `http://kadiemqazzaz.com` but I want `Nginx` to serve only `http://atlasalgorithms.kadiemqazzaz.com`.

I declared only `atlasalgorithms.kadiemqazzaz.com` in the `server_name` so what am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rule `server_name atlasalgorithms.kadiemqazzaz.com;` is actually only matching `http://atlasalgorithms.kadiemqazzaz.com`.

But there is the only server block in the conf file. This means that this also serves as the `default` server. Since, `http://kadiemqazzaz.com` matches none, request is routed to the default server block.

> nginx tests only the request’s header field “Host” to determine which server the request should be routed to. If its value does not match any server name, or the request does not contain this header field at all, then nginx will route the request to the default server

Read more about nginx request routing [here](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/request_processing.html).

If you need a different routing for `http://kadiemqazzaz.com`, you should have another server block defining different rules.